# How to show selected value from database using Laravel Ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to show selected value from “subcategories” and “third_subcategories” database into dropdown list on page load

How to automatically selected value the current subcategories and third_subcategories id and populate it to the select box.

**Categories Table**

| Id Pk

| cat_name

| cat_slug

**Subcategories Table**

| Id Pk

| subcat_name

| subcat_slug

| cat_id FK

**third_subcategories Table**

| Id PK

| third_subcategories_name

| third_subcategories_slug

| cat_id FK

| subcat_id FK

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li2V4.png

**Controller**

```
public function editData(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request->category_id))
    {

        $cat = subcategories::where('cat_id', $request->category_id)->get();
        echo '<option value="">Choose option...</option>';
        foreach($cat as $cats)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$cats->id.'" selected>'.$cats->subcat_name.'</option>';
        }
    } elseif(!empty($request->subcategory_id))
    {
        $third_cat = third_subcategories::where('subcat_id', $request->subcategory_id)->get();
        echo '<option value="">Choose option...</option>';
        foreach($third_cat as $third_cats)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$third_cats->id.'" selected>'.$third_cats->third_subcat_name.'</option>';
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="category">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select dynamic" name="category" id="category" data-dependent="subcategory" required>
        <option value="">Choose option...</option>
        <?php $cats = DB::table('categories')->get(); ?>
        @foreach($cats as $cat)
        <option value="{{$cat->id}}" @if($cat->id == $product->cat_id)selected="selected" @endif>{{ $cat->cat_name}}</option>
                            
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="subcategory">Subcategory</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select dynamic" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" required>
    <option value="">Choose option...</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="twosubcategory">2nd Subcategory</label>
    <select class="form-control custom-select" name="twosubcategory" id="twosubcategory" required>
    <option value="">Choose option...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("select[name='category']").on('change', function(){
      var category_id = $("select[name='category'] option:selected").val();
      var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
      if(category_id1){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'{{ route('editData')}}',
            data:{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            category_id:category_id},
            success:function(html){
                $('#subcategory').html(html);
                $('#twosubcategory').html('<option value="">Choose option...</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#subcategory').html('<option value="">Choose option...</option>');
        $('#twosubcategory').html('<option value="">Choose option...</option>'); 
    }
});

$("select[name='subcategory']").on('change', function(){
    var subcategory_id = $(this).val();
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    if(subcategory_id){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'{{ route('editData')}}',
            data:{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            subcategory_id:subcategory_id},
            success:function(html){
                $('#twosubcategory').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#twosubcategory').html('<option value="">Choose option...</option>'); 
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Does your ajax work? I mean, doesn't it populate the the select boxes for you after each ajax request?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes it works with ajax i don't need click the select option into dropdown list. so i want show automatically selected value the subcategories and third_categories from where "categories" foreign key. Please look this image the above mentioned.

Comment: Why do you "echo" subcategories and third_categories in your controller? you should return them. And second, basically you are selecting each select option in your loop, why?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi i am new to laravel. i don't think it maybe my mistake to code. could you fix my code this above?

Comment: I will fix it. But, first I should know how you will know with subcategory and thir_category to be chosen when displayed?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes